# LINQ to SQL doesn't exist in my visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, sql, linq, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am learning about how to add a data access layer to my project.

I found this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470374.ASPX:

> 2. Right-click the App_Code folder and then click Add New Item. The Add New Item dialog box is displayed.
> 3. Under Visual Studio installed templates, select the LINQ to SQL Classes template and rename the file Tasks.dbml.
> 4. Click Add.

but when I right click I see this:

[image]

there is no `Visual Studio installed templates` nor `LINQ to SQL Classes`

Comment: @ta.speot.is what is the other solution so to add an data access layer please??

Comment: You can do your data access layer however you see fit. But I think what you're asking for is: Entity Framework.

Comment: @ta.speot.is so are you telling me that i should use Entity Framework to build my data access layer ?

Comment: Entity Framework might be your solution.

Comment: @losSebos do you have a tutorials for buiding data access layer using entity framework?

Comment: LINQ to SQL is designed specifically for SQL Server and is not really being developed further by Microsoft.  Entity Framework supports multiple platforms and third-parties can create their own EF providers for their own data sources.  Microsoft continue to vigorously develop EF and add more and more features.  LINQ to SQL still has its place but is a bit of a dead end.  EF gives you far greater scope for future projects.

Comment: @jmcilhinney can u give me a tutorial for buidng data access layer using EF ?

Comment: What version of VS? Mine is Premium and it has __way__ more things to add than yours, and includes Linq to Sql classes.

Comment: @user2059935 : you may find your answer bellow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under VS2102, in your solution explorer, right click on your project, and select "Add/New Element" (something like this, my VS version is in french..)

Then you might find : C# -> Data -> "Linq to Sql classes" (depending on your Visual studio version i guess)
or you can select "Entity Data Model", 
An assistant should appear to guide you through the rest of the process.

In your project classes you should then use your dataModel, and use Linq to make your requests.

I don't have everything in mind right now, you should check that tutorial : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/vstudio/bb399182(v=vs.100).aspx

Hint: the generated model has a partial class for all your table fields, this is usefull for creating another class of the same name to add specific functions, or fields ;)

Comment: I have opened 2010 project in 2012 and wanted to add `Linq to SQL` and I did not see it anywhere, even no entity framework template. Then I tried to add win form project and class library to the solution and voilá - all needed templates magically appeared. When there is only Console app project, those templates are not available.